# Imported value not changed

Tags: python-3.x

I have a python file like this,

```
# mod.py
count = 0

def inc():
    global count
    count = count + 1
```

In main1.py I'm importing `count` like this, and the value is correct:

```
import mod

mod.inc()
print(mod.count)
```

In main2.py I'm importing `count` directly, it is always zero:

```
import mod
from mod import count

mod.inc()
print(count)
```

What is the difference?

Comment: Because when you call `inc`, you also use `from modules import a` I guess, `modules` & `modules.a` are treat different in `sys.modules`.

Comment: You forgot to put `:` there.

Comment: @CoolCloud Can you provide an example?

Comment: What do you mean by _"and it will be the correct value_". What will the value be?

Comment: @CoolCloud updated question, attached multiple files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from mod import count
```

makes an *alias* named `count` of the *current* value bound to `mod.count` in the importing module's global scope. Initially, both names refer to the same value, so for mutable types, if they are mutated in-place (e.g. assigning to attributes, subscripts, etc.), it will be visible from both aliases. But if one of them is *reassigned* (a plain `name =` sort of assignment, or augmented assignment like `+=` for immutable types), the linkage goes away; they're different names bound to one object, and you rebound one of them to a completely different object.

When you read/assign `mod.count` directly, no aliasing is occurring; there is only one name, and all parties involved are reading and rebinding that same name.

In this case, `main2` makes a local name `count` that references the same object, `0`, stored in `mod`'s `count`. Then it call `mod.inc`, which rebinds the `count` in `mod`, but the alias in `main2` can't see that (you could query the reference count on CPython and see it went down, that's all); it happily remains bound to the original `0`, while `mod.count` got rebound to `1`.

If it helps, imagine the scenario in a non-import based case. If you have:

```
a = 0
b = a
a = a + 1
```

do you expect `b` to change to match `a`? The relationship between the import `count` in `main2` and `mod.count` is *exactly* the same as you see here; `a` (`mod.count`) is initially `0`, you made an alias to that value named `b` (`main2.count`), then you made `a` (`mod.count`) something else (`1`); `b` (`main2.count`) shouldn't be changed in that scenario though (in a language where it did, you'd need to add some way to differentiate references from copies; C++ does this with `int&` vs. `int`, but Python has no language-level equivalent to C++ references).

Answer (score 0):

You are importing count directly so even though you call inner function in the module, the value which is imported first won't change (in my view)

Answer (score 0):

Let's go step by step.

**case 1**

```
import mod
```

Here we have `mod` in the memory. `mod.count` is a field and `mod.inc` is a function. Trying to print `count` would result in an error.

```
mod.inc()
print(mod.count)
```

This increments `mod.count`, and thus, if we print `mod.count` we would get the 'correct' value.

**case 2**

```
import mod
```

again we import `mod` in our memory, which means we are allowed to use `mod.count` and `mod.inc`.

```
from mod import count
```

We import `count` in our memory. Therefore, we have imported two variables, namely `count` and `mod.count`. Although they are imported in a similar way, they are now referred to as two seperate variables.

`mod.inc()`

Here we increment `mod.count`, since that is the variable that is referred to by `mod.inc`.

`print(count)`

We print the count variable not incremented by `mod.inc`, and thus get zero.